# I can't connect MySQL (on Ubuntu 22.04 Host) connect to remote server (Ubuntu 22.04 on VMWare Guest)

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mysql-workbench, network, vmware

I want to create new MySQL connection to remote Django server that is inside virtual machine on VMWare (located at address 127.0.0.1 on port 33061). The problem is that MySQL shows the message "Unable to connect to localhost". I think it's probably due to the fact that Ubuntu on VMWare isn't even connected to the internet (I can't use either the ping command or the curl command, for example). Currently the mode used on VMWare is NAT.

I use VMWare because VirtualBox creates conflict problems, for example, with the Android emulator that I need to use for a university project.

The only alternative is therefore to use Virtualbox. In that case everything works fine. The problem is that I need to run both the remote server and an android emulator on Android Studio, but I can't get both to run (I get a Guru Meditation related error). Well, I'm trying to run the remote server on VMWare.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to fix this using port forwards within virtualbox for port 33061

Comment: Inside VirtualBox it is already set to 33061. However, I can't use Virtualbox because there are virtualization conflicts between the android emulator and the virtual machine. The only way is to use VMWare but networking doesn't work in that case.